# Como usar o javascript para enviar dados do Form para um endereço de email?

Tags: javascript, html, css, formulário, front-end

Bom dia, estou trabalhando em um código que usa um FORM com método POST e preciso que os dados desse FORM ao serem submetidos sejam encaminhados para um email e não para um servidor. Isso tudo utilizando apenas JavaScript, procurei mas não encontrei nos outros post's, encontrei soluções apenas com PHP. Se alguém puder me ajudar a como realizar essa Action usando JS.

```
<form class="formulario" action="" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você quer fazer não é possível pelo lado do cliente. De acordo com a própria [documentação do elemento `<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form):

> O elemento HTML `<form>` representa uma seção de um documento que contém controles interativos que permitem ao usuário submeter informação a um determinado **servidor web**.

Desse modo, levando em conta que servidores de e-mail não são, de fato, "servidores web", não é possível enviar dados a eles. Geralmente servidores de e-mail utilizam outros protocolos, como o SMTP, diferentes dos protocolos usados pela web.

O máximo que você pode fazer é utilizar o protocolo `mailto`, que geralmente abre o cliente de e-mail padrão do sistema operacional com os campos já pré-definidos:

```html
<form method="get" action="mailto:foo@provider.com">
  <input name="subject" placeholder="Assunto" />
  <textarea name="body" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Note que isso não irá "enviar" o e-mail, apenas abrir o cliente padrão do sistema. Para saber mais como esse protocolo funciona no elemento `<form>`, consulte a [especificação](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#submit-mailto-headers).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo.